# Method update does not exist in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

It is very simple code to update an existing entry. save() is working perfectly. But update is not working. Here is my code:

```
Route::post('toggleFavourite',function(){
    try{
        $data = Request::all();
        extract($data);
        $favourite = \ItScholarBd\Api\Models\Favourite::where(['user_id'=> $user_id,'shop_id'=> $shop_id])->get();
        if(empty($favourite)){
            $favourite = new \ItScholarBd\Api\Models\Favourite;
            $favourite->user_id = $user_id;
            $favourite->shop_id = $shop_id;
            $favourite->status  = $status;
            $favourite->save();
        }else{
            $favourite->status  = $status;
            $favourite->update();
        }
        return response()->json(['status' =>1, 'data' => $favourite], 200); 
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        return response()->json(['status'=>0, 'status_text' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);

    }
});
```

I am getting the following response:

```
{"status":0,"status_text":"Method update does not exist."}
```

Comment: We have different definitions of “simple code”…

Answer (score 0):

the docs say the following for an update

```
$flight = App\Models\Flight::find(1);

$flight->name = 'New Flight Name';

$flight->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only thing you have to change to make your code work is replace `$favourite->update();` with `$favourite->save();`, but I tried to make your code a little bit simpler:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use ItScholarBd\Api\Models\Favourite;

Route::post('toggleFavourite', function (Request $request) {
    try {
        $user_id = $request->get('user_id');
        $shop_id = $request->get('shop_id');
        $status = $request->get('status');

        // get the existing favourite or a new instance
        $favourite = Favourite::where(['user_id' => $user_id, 'shop_id' => $shop_id])->firstOrNew();

        // check if it exists in the database
        if (!$favourite->exists()) {
            $favourite->user_id = $user_id;
            $favourite->shop_id = $shop_id;
        }

        $favourite->status = $status;
        $favourite->save();

        return response()->json(['status' => 1, 'data' => $favourite], 200);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return response()->json(['status' => 0, 'status_text' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
    }
});
```

PS:

You should add [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation) to your route, so you don't just accept and store any values that are being sent with the request in the database.

Answer (score -1):

From my observation, I come to a conclusion:
update is only work on an OBJECT of find($id) method. The following code works perfectly:

```
try {
        $data = Request::all();
        extract($data);
        $favourite = Favourite::where(['user_id' => $user_id, 'shop_id' => $shop_id]);
        if (!$favourite->count()) {
            $favourite = new Favourite;
            $favourite->user_id = $user_id;
            $favourite->shop_id = $shop_id;
            $favourite->status = $status;
            $favourite->save();
        }else{
            $favourite  = $favourite->get()->toArray();
            $favourite = Favourite::find($favourite[0]['id']);
            $favourite->status = $status;
            $favourite->update();
            
        }
        return response()->json(['status' => 1, 'data' => $favourite], 200);
} catch (Exception $ex) {

    return response()->json(['status' => 0, 'status_text' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
}
```